# How to connect to cloud foundry by pushing a txt file?

Tags: git, cloud-foundry

Currently, I am able to connect to cloud foundry by using the CLI. But I was wondering if it is possible to connect to cloud foundry by pushing a txt file.

**Command Line**

```
$ cf login -a https://api.example.com -u username@example.com
API endpoint: https://api.example.com

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

Select an org (or press enter to skip):
1. example-org
2. example-other-org

Org> 1
Targeted org example-org

Select a space (or press enter to skip):
1. development
2. staging
3. production

Space> 1
Targeted space development
```

**Txt File**

Right here I am attempting to create a txt file with all the credentials above so I do not have to go through command line to get into my org and space. I am not sure if this is possible but I have been surfing around github repos and found this.

```
CF_DOMAIN=dev.app.cloud.example.com
CF_TARGET=api.${CF_DOMAIN}
CF_ORG=example-org
CF_SPACE=development
CF_APP_NAME=Push-This-File
CF_CONFIG_SERVER=config-server-test

//Looks like User and password and build are being called in from somewhere
# CF_USER, CF_PASSWORD, and CF_BUILD are required to be set by the CI build
CF_BUILD=${CF_BUILD:-${PIPELINE}}
```

**Findings**

I found that config.json under .cf folder, saves all your inputs. I guess what I am trying to attempt should be simliar to this file?

Comment: Why not just create a script (or cf plugin if you want to get fancy) to do this for you?  You could call it `my-cf-login` or something like that.  The script would read your settings and take care of calling the right cf cli commands to log you in.  Whenever you need to login, just run the script.  As a side note, you really shouldn't leave your credentials laying around on your system (in a script or text file).  It's not secure, which is why the cli does not do this like @dkoper explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cf CLI does not use any of those environment variables.
The `~/.cf/config.json` file stores a few "session" variables, including your targeted org and space, access and refresh tokens. It does not store your password. So when your refresh token expires, you will have to log in again.
The format of the config.json file is not published and may change with any CLI upgrade, but it's open source so nothing stopping you from trying to edit it anyway.

If your current refresh token expires too quickly for your needs, you could look into obtaining a long-lived refresh token. This requires admin permissions to UAA.
First, you'd use the `uaac` tool to add an OAuth client, and obtain a refresh token for it. Then, you can add the new client's id and secret, and the refresh token, to the CLI's config.json. For details, see [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/919#issuecomment-268699211).

Comment: It looked similar to the config.json file. What I was trying to figure out is what the text file actually doing. Not specifically trying to create a config.json file. I thought the user on github was using this file to connect the cloud foundry without manually entering their credentials.

Comment: If I have not answered your question, could you rephrase, and maybe include a link to the file on github you are referring to?

Comment: It's a private github. The user had this cfenv file, and a generic.yml. I am just trying to understand the purpose of it. His cfenv file is exactly the same as I posted.

Comment: Apparently the file is for something called goCD.